# Destroy a movie Clip and everything in it

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am making a game with flash as3. I create a movieclip that contains all of the games content within it. I pretty much encapsulated the game within this one movie clip. after the game is over I remove the movieclip off the screen. but yet, all the other movieclips within the main movieclip still keep playing.

I could create a deconstructor that removes all the items. but that seems like much to do. is there something easier ?

I tried making the movieclip null. but all the other movieclips Timers keep going off still and causes errors to go off.

Comment: Try Destroying the container of all the movie clips

Answer (score 1):

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,myButton_Clicked);
...
function myButton_Clicked(event:MouseEvent)
{
    this.removeChild(this.getChildByName("myMovieClip"))
}
```

try this!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must remove listeners in the sub movies, otherwise they can't be garbage collected when you try to remove or nullify the main clip. You could add a destroy(); method in each of the sub-clips that does this and call that from the parent clip.